# JMX Timer vs Java util timer vs ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, timer, jmx, weblogic12c

what is the main difference b/t ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor vs java.util.Timer vs javax.management.timer.Timer? what is advantage of one over the another? What is the best design for scheduling two jobs to run daily starting right after the server comes up?

One example i've seen had extended and attached [NotificationListener](http://edelstein.pebbles.cs.cmu.edu/jadeite/main.php?api=java6&state=class&package=javax.management&class=NotificationListener) with the JMX Timer.

```
public class TestNotificationListener implements NotificationListener {
    javax.management.timer.Timer timer = new Timer();

    public void init() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date1 = calendar.getTime();
        Date date2 = calendar.getTime();

        timer.addNotificationListener(this, null, "some handback object");

        int job1Id = timer.addNotification("type1", "Order", this, date1, 10000);
        int job2Id = timer.addNotification("type2", "Inventory ", this, date2, 10000);

        timer.start();
    }
    public void handleNotification(Notification notif, Object handback) {
        ...
    }
}
```

another example use the Timer directly...

```
public class TestNotificationListener extends ApplicationLifecycleListener {

    public void postStart(final ApplicationLifecycleEvent evt) {
        java.util.Timer Timer1 = new Timer();       
        Timer1.schedule(new Task1(), 10000);

        java.util.Timer Timer2 = new Timer();
        final SocialMediaCachingTask smcCacheTask = new SocialMediaCachingTask();
        Timer2.schedule(new Task2(), 10000);
    }
}
```

and finally i've seen the use of [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)

```
public class TestNotificationListener extends ApplicationLifecycleListener {

    public void postStart(final ApplicationLifecycleEvent evt) {
        Scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
        Scheduler.schedule(new Task1(Scheduler), 10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Scheduler2 = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
        Scheduler2.schedule(new Task2(Scheduler2), 10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Comment: The doc for `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` that you linked gives explicit details on why it is better to use than `java.util.Timer` for multiple threads.  `java.util.Timer`, which works with `TimerTask`, `javax.management.timer.Timer` does not. What other info are you looking for?

Comment: What about the difference b/t **ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor** and  **NotificationListener**. What is the best approach in weblogic env?